# DIV's side by side within a container

Tags: html, css

I am working on an internal program for work that is essentially built on PHP. My problem is that I have a a header, a side navigation, the main content (to the right of the nav) and a footer. [Rough Layout Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whLdr.png)

My issue is that I have two DIV's within a container, the nav is set to a percentage with a minimum width, and the content section is set to take the remaining space. In total both the nav and content should take about 91% of the screen real estate. [Whats Happening after shrinking the browser a bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhwwU.png)

My CSS looks like this for the fields I think are relevant:

```
    .container{
        width: 100%;
        float: inline-block;
    }
    .header{
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: lightblue;
        width: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
    .header h1{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 40px;
        text-indent: 50px;
    }
    .msg_alert{
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        width: 95%;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .err_msg_alert{
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        width: 95%;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .menu{
        float: left;
        width: 13%;
        border: 3px solid grey;
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        border-radius: 15px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        min-width: 200px;
    }
    .menu a{
        float: left;
        color: black;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
        margin: 3px;
        background-color: lightblue;
        width: 40%;
        min-width: 150px;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
    .menu a:hover{
        background-color: grey;
        color: black;
    }
    .menu ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .menu li{
        padding: 8px;
        margin-bottom: 7px;
    }
    .content{
        float: left;
        width: 78%;
        padding: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        /*border: 3px solid red;*/
    }
    .footer{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: lightgrey;
        border-radius: 15px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Everything displays properly if the browser is in full screen but when I shrink it down to about 3/4's of the browser size the nav stays where it should be but the contents move below.

I have setup a mobile version which works perfectly but the desktop mode is what I am having issues with.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as `float: inline-block`

Comment: Is this what you are after ? https://jsfiddle.net/a8vs9bfr/38/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution-

```
<div class="header"></div>
  <div class="menu_content">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>

    .menu{
    width: 13%;
    border: 3px solid grey;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
.content{
    width: calc(100% - 21.7%);
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
.menu_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.menu_content::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you. Question, why the '.menu_content::after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}'

Answer (score 0):

Well, although the widths of `.menu` and `.content` might add up to 100% or less in a wider format, due to the `min-width` pixel setting of `.menu`, they will become *wider* than 100% when you decrease the window width, since the 200px of `min-width: 200px;` will become much more than the 13% width you define for it. So (since both are floats), `.content` will go *below* `.menu`, because there isn't enough space anymore for it next to  `.content`.

To avoid that, you can wrap both of these in a `div` container and assign `display: flex` to that. Additionally, add `flex-shrink: 0;` (= allowed to get smaller)  to `.content`. This should basically do the trick. (There are other details , but just check out some tutorial about flex - it's really not complicated at all.)

Another approach would be to define the menu width as 200px (fixed) and the width for `.content` as `width: calc(100% -200px)` - The full width of the parent minus 200px, whatever the width of the parent is.

(This doesn't calculate padding, margins etc. - you would have to consider that in the "real" values you use)

Comment: Thanks @Johannes but for what every reason I couldn't get it to work. I will be reading up about Flex. Seems to be a very interesting tool I am not taking advantage of.